# Difference between JScrollPane.getViewportBorderBounds() and JScrollPane.getViewport()

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jviewport

What is the difference between

> ```
> JScrollPane.getViewportBorderBounds()
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> JScrollPane.getViewport()
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> JscrollPane.getVisibleRect()
> ```

First two are returning same dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getViewportBorderBounds()` returns Rectangle which represents the bounds of the viewport border

`getViewport()` returns current JViewport.

`getVisibleRect()` returns visible rectangle of the JScrollPane (including borders and scroll bars), which is inherited from JComponent.

I don't see any comparability among these three methods. They are telling you different things. Read for more details on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html

Answer (score 0):

With  different LookAndFeel, getViewportBorderBounds() and getViewport() will give different values.